Insert a char just before a particular set of words using Regex
I want to use GREP/Regex in Adobe InDesign. Following is the sample data:
Rat: a mammal. Camel: an animal who lives in desert. An aeroplane: a machine that flys. The muddy water: water full of mud and dirt. Also filthy water. A four letter word: A word containing four letters. Test: a way to prove your worth.
I want to put a pipe-in "|" character or a unicode character of my choice, immediately before the words marked in bold.
e.g: |Rat: the description of rat. |Camel: description of camel. |An Aeroplane: description of an aeroplane. |The muddy water: description .... and so on.
How can I achieve this using Regex/Grep in Adobe InDesign.

Could you share with us what you have tried so far, and any research that you have done? Are you looking for words in bold, or are you just using bold here in this question to indicate the words you want to find?

Grep is used only to find a pattern, it can't do replacement. What is the regex flavour used in adobe indesign? What have you tried, what are the rules to define the place where insert the pipe?

I have used following:
\w+( \w+)*:
but I want to target the before and not after the selection. Is there any way to target the point just before the bold mark? It uses PCRE flavour. I am not very sure about it.

Is the text actually in bold in your InDesign document?

No it is not bold. I made it bold here just to show where I want the pipe char.

It seems you want to match the position just before 1 or more words that are followed by a colon, don't you?
You said you are using PCRE flavour, so, use this:

Find: (?<=^|\. )(?=\w+(?: \w+)*:)
Replace: |


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
